# On mouse over specific text show using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have li elements in that image and text will be there. Bydefault text will be hide. On mousehovor i want to show respective text.

html as follows:

```
<div class="icon-list-fixed-right">
<ul class="elementor-icon-list-items">
    <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
        <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>                      </span>
            <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">Whatsapp Us</span>
    </li>
    <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
        <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-video"></i>                     </span>
                <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">Virtual consultation</span>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

js will be below:

```
jQuery(".icon-list-fixed-right .fa-whatsapp").on("mouseover", function () {
       jQuery('this').find('span.elementor-icon-list-text').find('span.elementor-icon-list-text').css('opacity','1');
        //console.log(jQuery('this').closest('li.elementor-icon-list-item').find('span.elementor-icon-list-text'));
});
```

css will be as follows:

```
.icon-list-fixed-right .elementor-icon-list-text {
    opacity:0;
}
```

On mousehover i am not getting text. If anyone have idea what exact wrong then let me know.

Comment: Remove `' '` from `this`. ->  `jQuery(this)`

Comment: Also there is nothing inside your `i` with the class `fa-whatsapp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to remove the `''` that is surrounding your `this` in `jquery('this')`

Second your ´text´ is not a child of the icon, so you can't use `.find()`

You have to do:

```
jQuery(".icon-list-fixed-right .fa-whatsapp").on("mouseover", function() {
  jQuery(this).parent().next(".elementor-icon-list-text").css('opacity', '1');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(".icon-list-fixed-right .fa-whatsapp").on("mouseover", function() {
  jQuery(this).parent().next(".elementor-icon-list-text").css('opacity', '1');
});
```

```css
.elementor-icon-list-text {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-list-fixed-right">
  <ul class="elementor-icon-list-items">
    <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
      <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fab fa-whatsapp">hover me</i>                      
      </span>
      <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">Whatsapp Us</span>
    </li>
    <li class="elementor-icon-list-item">
      <span class="elementor-icon-list-icon">
           <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-video">hover me</i>                     
      </span>
      <span class="elementor-icon-list-text">Virtual consultation</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can its possible to add animation effect text come from right to left or left to right?

Comment: @Praff Yes, you can find lots of examples if your google, text from left to right appear